# angular scope initialization sometimes empty

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with angular 1.5 and a python/mongodb api. 
The api is working fine (consistent and fast), but sometimes when I load a page with a form the data fields are empty.

The app uses `ui.router` to associate the `chap` state with the correct url and the `chapController`. I type that url into the address bar and hit return to load the page. In the controller, the `path/to/api` returns json data.

Here's a simplified version of the controller:

```
angular.module('configurer')
.controller('chapController', function($scope, $http, $state) {
    var url='path/to/api';
    $http.get(url).success(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
    });

    $scope.save = function()( {
        $http.post(url, $scope.data).success(function() {
            $state.go('home', {reload:true});
        });
    });
```

The view looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">Save Changes</button>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" ng-model="data.chap.name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="title" type="text" title="title" ng-model="data.chap.title" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Usually the form comes up populated with data but sometimes the fields are blank (using the same url).
I can reload the page from the browser and then it will populate, but of course that's not a good user experience.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to initiate $scope.data with <ng-init>

Comment: I'm looking at the doc here and I don't see how to use it in my context: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit  My data is a large json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research plus trial-and-error, I think I've got the answer. The reason the scope wasn't binding to the data is that there was no data: my server was sending a 304 "not modified" response.

So of course it *couldn't* bind with non-existent data but the http response was still counted as success. Seems like this would be a common 'gotcha'.

What worked for me is to add a config object to each http.get call, like this

```
http.get(url, {cache:true}).success(function(data) { etc...
```

My guess is that you could also set `max-age` and `public` on the http request headers so the server cannot respond with a 304. That didn't seem like the most efficient thing to do, so I went with using cache on the client so the server isn't even bothered.

This is working for me, but if problems pop up again, I'll repost.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `ui.router`, I recommend using [`resolve`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) for this.

Example:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('chap', {
    // ...
    resolve: {
      data: function($http){
        return $http.get(...);
      }
    }
  });
```

and in your controller:

```
angular
  .module('configurer')
  .controller('chapController', function(data, $scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.data = data;
  }
```

Comment: I cannot get it to fail today, I'll return when I can reproduce. I'm reading about resolve now and it seems like it's for cases of nested states, but I don't have any of those.

Comment: resolve is useful for any state in which you want to ensure data is present *before* moving to that particular state.  It's very relevant in cases where you might have a load overlay on your views, and want to block the entire view ou until data has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes data won't bind with the scope. can you check by including this line

```
$scope.data = data;
$scope.$apply();
```

Inside success handler. 
I am not sure, it may work. please try

Comment: thanks, but the doc says that http calls finish with $scope.apply: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html so I can't see how calling apply again would help.Still, as soon as I can reproduce the problem I'll see if it does help.